# Polynomials - Solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

How I can find the exact solutions of this polynomial?

I can not get to the exact roots of the polynomial ... what methods occupy for this "problem"?

$$x^3+3x^2-7x+1=0$$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Reduction_to_a_depressed_cubic and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(polynomial) Gauss's lemma states that, if you can factorise a polynomial (with integer coefficients) into a product of two polynomials with rational coefficients, then you can make those two polynomials have integer coefficients. In particular, if this polynomial has a rational root, then it has an integer root, and that root must divide +1 (the constant term), so it must be +1 or -1. Neither of these works, so there are no rational solutions to this polynomial. So you're going to have to use a cubic formula or similar, like in the above comment.

Answer (score 2):

> How I can find the exact solutions of this polynomial?
>
> I can not get to the exact roots of the polynomial

You have a real polynomial of the third degree with real coefficients. There are exact formulas to find the roots of any polynomial of this kind.

A general cubic equation of the form 
$$
\begin{equation*}
ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d=0,\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
$$
can be transformed by the substitution 
$$
x=t-\frac{b}{a}\tag{2}
$$ 
into the reduced cubic equation 
$$
\begin{equation*}
t^{3}+pt+q=0.\tag{3}
\end{equation*}
$$
In the present case, we have
$$
\begin{equation*}
x^{3}+3x^{2}-7x+1=0,\quad a=1,b=3,c=-7,d=1.\tag{$\mathrm{A}$}
\end{equation*}
$$

For $x=t-1$, we get the reduced equation
$$
\begin{equation*}
t^{3}-10t+10=0,\qquad p=-10,q=10.\tag{$\mathrm{B}$}
\end{equation*}
$$

It is known from the classical theory of the cubic equation that when  the *discriminant* 
$$
\Delta =q^{2}+\frac{4p^{3}}{27}=10^{2}+\frac{4\left(-10\right) ^{3}}{27}<0,\tag{$\mathrm{C}$}
$$
 *the three roots $t_k$ of $(3)$, with $k\in\{1,2,3\}$, are real and can be written in the following trigonometric form* $^1$

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
t_{k} &=&2\sqrt{-p/3}\cos \left( \frac{1}{3}\arccos \left( -\frac{q}{2}\sqrt{-27/p^3}\right) +\frac{(k-1)2\pi }{3}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}\tag{4}
$$

The roots of $(1)$ are thus

$$x_k=t_k-\frac{b}{a}.\tag{5}$$

Consequently,

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_{1} &=&2\sqrt{10/3}\cos \left( \frac{1}{3}\arccos \left( -5\sqrt{27/10^3}\right) \right) -1 \approx 1.4236, \\
x_{2} &=&2\sqrt{10/3}\cos \left( \frac{1}{3}\arccos \left( -5\sqrt{27/10^3}\right) +\frac{2\pi }{3}\right) -1 \approx -4.5771, \\
x_{3} &=&2\sqrt{10/3}\cos \left( \frac{1}{3}\arccos \left( -5\sqrt{27/10^3}\right) +\frac{4\pi }{3}\right) -1 \approx 0.15347.
\end{eqnarray*}\tag{$\mathrm{D}$}
$$

--

$^1$ A deduction can be found in [this post of mine](http://problemasteoremas.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/resolucao-da-equacao-do-3-%C2%BA-grau-ou-cubica/) in Portuguese.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to find the roots of cubic equations by algebraic means (which is what I take your question to mean). See [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Roots_of_a_cubic_function) for a thorough explanation which there is not much point in repeating here.

Interestingly enough, when the degree of the equation (i.e. the highest exponent of $x$ which in your case is $3$) is greater than 4, finding the roots algebraically is generally impossible.

Comment: It would be better to say "it is _generally_ impossible to find the roots algebraically" for a polynomial with degree greater than four.  There _are_ a number of special cases that can be managed using algebra...

Comment: I agree and recall having that wording in my head at some point during writing that. :)

Comment: I bring it up because, historically, there was a certain amount of wrestling with the problem of which quintic, sextic, etc. polynomial equations _could_ be solved using radicals, which finally led to the proofs that no general method could be produced.

Answer (score 0):

What about subdivision? It isn't particularly fast but it burns lots of hours...

$$f(x)=x^3+3x^2-7x+1=0\;\;;\;\;f(0)f\left(\frac12\right)<0\implies\;\text{there exists a root}\;\;\alpha\in\left(0,\frac12\right)$$

BTW, Descartes' Rule of signs tells us then that there are *exactly*two positive roots.

$$f(0)f\left(\frac14\right)<1\implies\;\text{a root is actually in}\;\;\left(0,\frac14\right)\;,\;\;etc.$$

Answer (score 0):

You may enjoy the trigonometric form of the solutions:

$$x = -1+\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{30} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{2 \pi j}{3} + \frac{1}{3}\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{13}{40}}\right)\right),\ j = 0,1,2$$

Answer (score 0):

The method described [here](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac11/fac11.html) is quite simple and neat.